# What are the configurations I need to set for mavros_extras distance_sensor plugin?

Tags: ros, pixhawk, mavros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

In my hexacoptor setup, the Lidarlite is directly connected to a Pixhawk FCU. The Pixhawk is connected to a single board computer on the hexacoptor.

My mavros launch file looks like this :

```
<launch>
  <arg name="fcu_url" default="serial:///dev/ttyTHS2:57600" />
  <arg name="gcs_url" default="udp://localhost:14556@localhost:14540" />
  <arg name="tgt_system" default="1" />
  <arg name="tgt_component" default="50" />
  <arg name="pluginlists_yaml" default="$(find mbzirc_system)/launch/field_tests/px4_pluginlists.yaml"/>
  <arg name="config_yaml" default="$(find mbzirc_system)/launch/field_tests/px4_config.yaml" />

  <node name="uav_control" pkg="control" type="mavros_control" output="screen">
    <param name="autopilot" value="apm" />
  </node>
  <node name="mavros" pkg="mavros" type="mavros_node" output="screen">
    <param name="fcu_url" value="$(arg fcu_url)" />
    <param name="gcs_url" value="$(arg gcs_url)" />
    <param name="target_system_id" value="$(arg tgt_system)" />
    <param name="target_component_id" value="$(arg tgt_component)" />

    <!-- <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mavros)/launch/px4_blacklist.yaml" /> -->

    <!-- enable heartbeat send and reduce timeout -->
    <param name="conn_heartbeat" value="5.0" />
    <param name="conn_timeout" value="5.0" />
    <!-- automatically start mavlink on USB -->
    <param name="startup_px4_usb_quirk" value="true" />

    <!-- load blacklist, config -->
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg pluginlists_yaml)" />
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(arg config_yaml)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

My px4_config.yaml looks like this:

```
# Common configuration for PX4 autopilot
#
# node:
startup_px4_usb_quirk: true

# --- system plugins ---

# sys_status & sys_time connection options
conn:
  heartbeat_rate: 1.0    # send hertbeat rate in Hertz
  timeout: 10.0          # hertbeat timeout in seconds
  timesync_rate: 10.0    # TIMESYNC rate in Hertz (feature disabled if 0.0)
  system_time_rate: 1.0  # send system time to FCU rate in Hertz (disabled if 0.0)

# sys_status
sys:
  min_voltage: 10.0   # diagnostics min voltage
  disable_diag: false # disable all sys_status diagnostics, except heartbeat

# sys_time
time:
  time_ref_source: "fcu"  # time_reference source
  timesync_avg_alpha: 0.6 # timesync averaging factor

# --- mavros plugins (alphabetical order) ---

# 3dr_radio
tdr_radio:
  low_rssi: 40  # raw rssi lower level for diagnostics

# actuator_control
# None

# command
cmd:
  use_comp_id_system_control: false # quirk for some old FCUs

# dummy
# None

# ftp
# None

# global_position
global_position:
  frame_id: "fcu"           # pose and fix frame_id
  rot_covariance: 99999.0   # covariance for attitude?
  tf:
    send: false               # send TF?
    frame_id: "local_origin"  # TF frame_id
    child_frame_id: "fcu_utm" # TF child_frame_id

# imu_pub
imu:
  frame_id: "fcu"
  # need find actual values
  linear_acceleration_stdev: 0.0003
  angular_velocity_stdev: !degrees 0.02
  orientation_stdev: 1.0
  magnetic_stdev: 0.0

# local_position
local_position:
  frame_id: "fcu"
  tf:
    send: false
    frame_id: "local_origin"
    child_frame_id: "fcu"
    send_fcu: false

# param
# None, used for FCU params

# rc_io
# None

# safety_area
safety_area:
  p1: {x:  1.0, y:  1.0, z:  1.0}
  p2: {x: -1.0, y: -1.0, z: -1.0}

# setpoint_accel
setpoint_accel:
  send_force: false

# setpoint_attitude
setpoint_attitude:
  reverse_throttle: false   # allow reversed throttle
  tf:
    listen: false           # enable tf listener (disable topic subscribers)
    frame_id: "local_origin"
    child_frame_id: "attitude"
    rate_limit: 10.0

# setpoint_position
setpoint_position:
  tf:
    listen: false           # enable tf listener (disable topic subscribers)
    frame_id: "local_origin"
    child_frame_id: "setpoint"
    rate_limit: 50.0

# setpoint_velocity
# None

# vfr_hud
# None

# waypoint
mission:
  pull_after_gcs: true  # update mission if gcs updates

# --- mavros extras plugins (same order) ---

# distance_sensor (PX4 only)
distance_sensor:
  hrlv_ez4_pub:
    id: 0
    frame_id: "hrlv_ez4_sonar"
    orientation: ROLL_180 # RPY:{180.0, 0.0, 0.0}
    field_of_view: 0.0  # XXX TODO
    send_tf: true
    sensor_position: {x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z:  -0.1}
  lidarlite_pub:
    id: 1
    frame_id: "lidarlite_laser"
    orientation: ROLL_180
    field_of_view: 0.0  # XXX TODO
    send_tf: true
    sensor_position: {x:  0.0, y:  0.0, z:  -0.1}
  sonar_1_sub:
    subscriber: true
    id: 2
    orientation: ROLL_180
  laser_1_sub:
    subscriber: true
    id: 3
    orientation: ROLL_180

## Currently available orientations:
#    Check http://wiki.ros.org/mavros/Enumerations
##

# image_pub
image:
  frame_id: "px4flow"

# mocap_pose_estimate
mocap:
  # select mocap source
  use_tf: false   # ~mocap/tf
  use_pose: true  # ~mocap/pose

# px4flow
px4flow:
  frame_id: "px4flow"
  ranger_fov: !degrees 0.0  # XXX TODO
  ranger_min_range: 0.3     # meters
  ranger_max_range: 5.0     # meters

# vision_pose_estimate
vision_pose:
  tf:
    listen: false           # enable tf listener (disable topic subscribers)
    frame_id: "local_origin"
    child_frame_id: "vision"
    rate_limit: 10.0

# vision_speed_estimate
vision_speed:
  listen_twist: false

# vibration
vibration:
  frame_id: "vibration"

# vim:set ts=2 sw=2 et:
```

And my px4_pluginlists.yaml looks like this:

```
plugin_blacklist:
# common
- safety_area
# extras
- image_pub
- vibration

plugin_whitelist:
- distance_sensor
#- 'sys_*'
```

These configs I copied directly from mavros Git repo and I understand that I need to change them for my setup.

How can I change the distance_sensor plugin config such that I can read the lidar data to the onboard computer from the pixhawk via mavros?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253179/what-are-the-configurations-i-need-to-set-for-mavros_extras-distance_sensor-plugin?/) by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 849 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

APM do not support DISTANCE_SENSOR message => plugin don't do anything.
APM has it's own specific message that carries ground radar data. You should write plugin.

Why you use PX4-specific configs with APM firmware?

---

Originally posted by [vooon](https://answers.ros.org/users/10566/vooon/) with karma: 404 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [janindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26723/janindu/) on 2017-01-31**:
I fooled around with PX4 specific configs. Thank you! Gonna start writing a plugin myself. Thanks!

**Comment by [hesham](https://answers.ros.org/users/76126/hesham/) on 2021-07-22**:
Could you please link or refer to any guidelines by designing the Ardupilot configs and how to write it?